# Query posts by category AND custom field, then ORDERBY another custom field - help!

Tags: customization, categories, custom-field, query-posts

OK I need to query posts using the following criteria:

category_name=office,
meta_key=featured_post,
meta_value=Yes

and order these results using a second custom field which has a numerical value

meta_key=prop_order

I have the following query which pulls the correct posts, but doesn't order them by the second custom field.

```
<?php $recent = new WP_Query("category_name=office&meta_key=featured_post&meta_value=Yes&posts_per_page=3&orderby=date&order=ASC"); while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post(); ?>
```

However since I'm already using a custom field in the query I can't use orderby=meta_value.

I found the following SQL query on the forums but can't get it working.

```
    <?php
 global $wpdb;
 global $post;
 $querystr = "
SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS proporder ON(
$wpdb->posts.ID = proporder.post_id
AND proporder.meta_key = 'prop_order'
)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = 3
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND $wpdb->wpostmeta.meta_key = 'featured_post' 
AND $wpdb->wpostmeta.meta_value = 'Yes' 
ORDER BY proporder.meta_value ASC
 ";

 $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Dave

Comment: Do you have to use the meta_key prop_order? Or could you use a posts/pages reorder plugin? Then you can drag and drop the posts into the correct order, and use orderby=menu_order, order=ASC or order=DESC in your query then the whole thing would be WP_Query("category_name=office&meta_key=featured_post&meta_value=Yes&posts_per_page=3&orderby=menu_order&order=ASC");?

Comment: Hi @ Eileen, thanks for replying! In truth I need a number of these queries across my site, using different categories etc so I need to have a query like this in the template rather than using a plugin, unfortunately.

Comment: I had a second look, as I thought I may be able to use your suggestion, unfortunately I'm using custom post types aswell and those plugins don't seem to be able to manage them individually.

Comment: Use this plugin for post reorder, it works for custom post type and regular posts. It pusts a redorder button under each menu item in the post types. I really like it and it works great. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-types-order/

Comment: Did you ever get this working properly? I need exactly the same thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your input guys. Didnt realise i'd never posted back on this! Thanks to Ethan and a few other foums heres the working code:

```
<?php
 global $wpdb;
 global $post;
 $querystr = "
SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS proporder ON(
$wpdb->posts.ID = proporder.post_id
AND proporder.meta_key = 'prop_order'
)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS propfeatured ON(
$wpdb->posts.ID = propfeatured.post_id
AND propfeatured.meta_key = 'featured_post'
)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = 4
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND propfeatured.meta_value='Yes'
ORDER BY proporder.meta_value ASC
 ";

 $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
 //print_r($querystr);
?>
<?php foreach ($pageposts as $post): ?>
<?php setup_postdata($post); ?>

<!-- some post stuff here -->

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

where 'prop_order' and 'featured_post' are the custom fields and posts are returned that match featured_post='Yes' and then they are ordered by 'prop_order' in ASC order.

hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I ran your query on my local workstation. It looks like there is a typo:

You should have $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value not $wpdb->wpostmeta.meta_value (used twice).